# backdrop-filter causes unwanted "anti-aliasing" on fonts

Tags: html, css, electron

I am using Electron to build an app, and I encountered a weird issue.

I am trying to use a Pixel font to fit the style of application I am making, 
however, when I use the following CSS code on a container:

```css
backdrop-filter: blur();
```

This seems to cause the pixel font to become anti-aliased, my best theory for this is that the blur is effecting the outside edges of the font, but I don't know how or why because the font is (or should be) drawn on top of the container.

[image: image of blur causing anti aliasing]

I've "worked around" the issue by not using pixel fonts, but a few people have pointed out that pixel fonts would work better for the aesthetic.